# Magento 2.2.6 VAT not passed to paypal

Tags: paypal, magento2.2.6

We have noticed since upgrading from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.2.6 that wheres the VAT figure was being passed and stored in the paypal transaction it is not now - always 0 - even though the total figure is correct.

This is an issue as we rely on this for paypal reconciliation with the shop.

Has anyone else found this or know if there is a fix.

See example from this morning.

[image: Paypal transaction without VAT showing]
[image: Magento 2.2.6 same transaction with VAT]

Comment: Did you trace the issue? Get any log files?

Comment: Where would be the best place to look for the paypal API logs? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Solution to achieve this issue is, Need to override the core magento's Paypal Nvp model file.

Steps are below:

1. Create a custom module and in the `di.xml`, define the Paypal function as below:

   ```
   <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp" type="Vendor\Namespace\Model\Api\Nvp" />
   ```
2. Copy the Magento's Core `vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php` to specified path in the `di.xml`.
3. You will find the `public function call($methodName, array $request)` and add the below code in the initial of the function.

> ```
> if($methodName != 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails'){
>    $request['ITEMAMT']=$request['fee'];
> }
> ```

4. Add [this](https://pastebin.com/Jt5UNZhp) file in `Vendor\Modulename\Model\Total\Fee`. Here I used variable `fee`. Use your custom variable.

It will work now. Add comment if you need clarifications.

Comment: HI thank you - I will give this a go and get back you - looks good.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it is worked.

Comment: OK so I am getting this exception when making that change:  main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: AMT

Comment: Made this change - first few lines of function: public function call($methodName, array $request)
    {
        if($methodName != 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails'){
           $request['ITEMAMT']=$request['AMT'];
        }
        $request = $this->_addMethodToRequest($methodName, $request);
        $eachCallRequest = $this->_prepareEachCallRequest($methodName);

Comment: Change `$request['AMT'];` to your variable.

Comment: Please Check my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90874/discussion-between-saravanan-ds-and-zipnfc).

Comment: Hi - tried the chat but no answer - so signing off for today, but not sure this is correct for me even though in the right space.  I just need the VAT amount sent via the paypal API so that paypal receives it as the VAT amount.

Comment: I tried to reach you through chat. You were not available.

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: Hi. I got diverted onto something else so will ping you when I can get back to it. Still not convinced this is going to solve my VAT issue but might be wrong.